# indexing huge table record in apache solr cloud

Tags: solr, cassandra

I have a Cassandra table with 9 million records and my data size is 500 MB . I have a Solr cloud with 3 nodes(3 shards and 2 replicas)with three external Zookeeper ensemble. My Cassandra is a 1 node cluster. I am trying to index this table using Apache Solr but my query is getting timeout as soon as i am starting full import .

I am able to `cqlsh` and fetch records but i am failing in indexing it . 
Here is my attached `solr.log`...

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * from counter.series Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:69)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:318)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:279)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:54)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:475)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: TimedOutException()
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:189)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.execute(CassandraStatement.java:205)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.executeStatement(JdbcDataSource.java:338)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:313)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: TimedOutException()
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:37865)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1562)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1547)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:468)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:494)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:164)
        ... 15 more
```

I want some help in indexing the table either batch wise or by using multiple threads . Any help or suggestion is welcomed..
db-data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver" url="jdbc:cassandra://192.168.0.7:9160/counter" user="cassandra" password="cassandra" autoCommit="true" />
        <document>
                <entity name="counter" query="SELECT * from counter.series;" autoCommit="true">
                        <field column="serial" name="serial" />
                        <field column="random" name="random" />
                        <field column="remarks" name="remarks" />
                        <field column="timestamp" name="timestamp" />
                 </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
```

schema.xml

```
<field name="remarks" type="string" indexed="false" stored="false" required="false" />
   <field name="serial" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="random" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="timestamp" type="string" indexed="false" stored="false" required="false" />
```

Comment: could you show your config files in Solr? I assume you're using DataStax integration?

Comment: @Mysterion i am able to index 10 MB of data but when i am trying to index 500MB of data i am getting timedout exception . I am not sure whether this error is because o indexing data uses one thread or should i index data using batch process and i need help in batch indexing .

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is the size of the payload of data sending to Solr. By default when no `batchSize` specified in `JdbcDataSource` it's got defaulted to 500. It looks like in your case it's too much. You should use smaller numbers or increase timeout settings on Solr side

Comment: I am still not able to index with setFetchSize=10 .